# Unable to select Resource in "Create Event Subscription" in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group, azure-eventgrid, azure-function-app

I'm able to select the following from a drop-down in the "Create Event Subscription" window for Event Grid:  (1) Topic Types (2) Subscription (3) Resource Group.

The drop-down for "Resource" begins to load after I select the Resource Group, however, nothing populates in it.  I have multiple storage accounts in this resource group.  Why aren't these resources showing up in the drop-down?  I am unable to create the Event Subscription until I select a Resource.  Is there an alternative way I can reference the resource in the 'Advanced Editor'?  I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?tabs=dotnet) from Microsoft, but I'm running into this roadblock in which the Resources don't populate in the drop-down.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only blobstorage accounts will be listed there. You need to create the storage account with kind 'blobstorage'.

```
blobStorageAccount=<blob_storage_account>

az storage account create --name $blobStorageAccount \
--location southeastasia --resource-group myResourceGroup \
--sku Standard_LRS --kind blobstorage --access-tier hot
```

If you create the storage with kind 'storage', it will not be listed there.

```
blobStorageAccount=<blob_storage_account>

az storage account create --name $blobStorageAccount \
--location southeastasia --resource-group myResourceGroup \
--sku Standard_LRS --kind blobstorage --access-tier hot
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, OK.  So it looks like the tutorial is incorrect since it specifies a kind of storage.

Comment: @TheDude The tutorial is ok. To complete this tutorial:

You must have completed the previous Blob storage tutorial: Upload image data in the cloud with Azure Storage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=dotnet